# When can we add a statistical touch to least square optimization problems?

Tags: regression, optimization, least-squares

I am trying to connect the dots between statistics and linear algebra/optimization.

As you know, Least Square problems are linear algebra  and optimization problems. But they also can be connected to statistics.

My questions are:

Lets say we want to find the $b$'s that minimize the sum of squares of $(y- Xb)$.  This is a Least Squares problem.

However, we also want to know the "significance" of such $b$'s.

It's here that we need to connect the Least Squares problem to statistics.

My question is: under what conditions can we do that?

We knew that the Gauss-Markov Theorem might play a role here. But the Gauss-Markov Theorem has several conditions.

More specifically, if we only care about the "significance" of the $b$'s, what are the "essential" conditions that we have to meet, in order for the $t$-stats to make sense?

To be more clear, we don't need the BLUE, we only need to be able to measure the $t$-stats...

Answer (score 1):

To be able to talk about the significance of the coefficients you need to know the distribution under the null hypothesis that the parameter is actually 0.  For the least squares estimate we can do that if we can estimate its distribution from a parametric family.  The most common approach is to assume a normally distributed error term for the model with mean 0 and constant variance.  If you want to get away from the parametric approach the bootstrap works in this case.  You can bootstrap residuals or bootstrap the vectors.  The bootstrap distribution for the regression parameter, serves the role of the t statistic in the parametirc approach, to decide on the significance of the regression parameter.

This can be generalized to other fit criteria such as MAD (minimizing the median absolute deviation)..

Comment: Thanks a lot Mike. In practice, can we assume the coefficients follow Normal distributions, since we have pretty large data (~1800 data points). We should be able to say that these coefficients are asymptotically Normal, right? With this assumption, we can plug in the formula of t-stats, am I right?

Comment: Operationally, how to do bootstrap and get the "significance" of the b's? Thank you!

Comment: Apply Monte Carlo to get a bootstrap histogram for the parameter estimate.  Construct say a two sided 95% bootstrap confidence interval for the regression parameter.  If 0 is not in the interval you call the parameter significant.

Comment: Normality of the coefficients depends on normality of the residuals. I don't see exactly how you invoke the CLT here since the estimate is not obtained as an average of iid random variables.

Comment: Please see the page 23 (about asymptotic normality) of this note: http://jackman.stanford.edu/classes/350B/07/asymptoticsforWeb.pdf

Comment: @Luna Note that the asymptotic normality require some conditions on the betas.  But if those conditions are mild enough to apply to your data then I gues you can use the asymptotic normality result for large n.

Comment: Oh how do I check if the iid condition of the errors is satisfied though? Thanks Mike!

Comment: It looks like the conditions that need checking relate to the design matrix X.

Comment: Hi Mike, seems to me that the condition 2 is almost always met in practice... I just have to check the condition 1... how to check that? Thanks!

Comment: @Luna Common practice for condition 1 is to look at the model residuals. (1) Check to make sure there is no significant autocorreltaion in the residuals (time taken as the order of observation if the data are not sequenced in time). (2) Subdivide the X square into regions and calculate the sample variance for the residuals in the regions.  Plot them to see whether or not they are nearly equal.  If in addition you want to include the normality assumption test the residuals for normality by goodness of fit (e.g. Shapiro-Wilk test) or look at the QQ plot as you have been.